# Expressing the sentence with clause: "X is a vector. The i_th element of X is ..."

Tags: clauses

I want to express "X is a vector. The i_th element of X is ..." with a clause. Which one is right:

- X is a vector, the i_th element of which is ...
- X is a vector, of which the i_th element is ...

Comment: X is a vector, **whose** i_th element is ...

Comment: Yes; Greybeard's suggestion is the most idiomatic (and least cluttered); neither of your suggestions is ungrammatical, but idiomaticity is at least as important. (2) sounds rarefied. (1) is passable. Greybeard's suggestion, A+. 'Whose' is used effortlessly for inanimate objects, notions etc by practised Anglophones ( 'a car whose left door is broken'; 'a war whose main objectives have been accomplished').